# PHP Warning: Division by zero error

Tags: php

I getting this error and not sure how to fix it. Line 162 is the first line in the php code. I looked at some of the related questions and all my quote marks seem to be in the right place

```
Per page:
<input type=text name=per_page value="<?php echo $en['per_page']; ?>" size=6> 
Go to page:
<select name=page size=1>

<?php 
$pages = ceil(sql_num_rows($result)/$en['per_page']); 
for ($k=1;$k<=$pages;$k++) 
   echo '<option value='.$k.($en[page] == $k ? ' selected':'').'>'.
     $k.'</option>';

echo '</select>';   
if ($en[page]<$pages) 
   echo '<input type=submit name=next value="Next page">';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `echo $en['per_page']` and make sure it's got the correct value. (I bet it doesnt).

Unrelated: `$en[page]` Should probably be `$en['page']` (assuming page is really not a constant)

Comment: something like this would fix the problem...
$pages = ceil(sql_num_rows($result)/($en['per_page'] == '0' ? '20' : $en['per_page']));

Answer (score 3):

What's the value of `$en['per_page']` (I'm guessing zero)

Answer (score 2):

Because you cannot have a denominator value of 0.

Check the value of $en['per_page'] > 0 prior to applying it to a division.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you divide by a variable, if the variable is 0 you will get that error.

The way to prevent it would be to check to ensure that $en['per_page'] is not zero, since that appears to be your only division and is probably where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a divide by zero error, then `$en['per_page']` may not be correct.  It's probably a zero value.

---

<strike>Also, all your HTML attributes need to be in quotes.
For example:</strike>

```
<input type=text name=per_page
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" name="per_page"
```

Your array indexes should be quoted too.

```
$en[page]
```

Should be:

```
$en['page']
```

Comment: They don't *need to be in quotes* ;) XHTML says they must be, HTML says they can be - [HTML spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

Comment: @Rudu: Ah, didn't realize that.  I've used XHTML for so long, that I got used to quoting all attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Per page:

```
<input type=text name=per_page value="<?php echo $en['per_page']; ?>" size=6>
```

Go to page:

```
<?php 
$pages = @ceil(sql_num_rows($result)/$en['per_page']); 
for ($k=1;$k<=$pages;$k++) 
   echo '<option value='.$k.($en[page] == $k ? ' selected':'').'>'.
     $k.'</option>';

echo '</select>';   
if ($en[page]<$pages) 
   echo '<input type=submit name=next value="Next page">';
?>
```

Just used @ before ceil / division.